# Google bot problem

Tags: asp.net, user-agent, googlebot

I have two websites with different content one written in native language and other one is in english for international users. 15% of international users somehow manage to enter native website and on international site vice versa.

I use .NET IP Location service to locate where is user came from and then redirect him to correct website in case he got there wrong. Problem is that Google bots from all around the world can be any country and have different IP's... So how i distinguish between those and real users so i can keep bots on my site while to redirect wrong type of users to right type of website?

Comment: IMO there's just about nothing more frustrating than going to a site and being redirected to a different but related version of the site than I requested. Especially when most sites that do this don't let me opt out of their "help" and use the version I was intending to land on.

Comment: Different languages, same site. It eases on average user who cannot see country flags or drop down menu with language choice. Although you can blame me as much as you can but you could learn little bit of usability and some tests on average PC user who sees nothing except BIG things on the screen

Comment: I only have a problem when the site doesn't let me undo their "help" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the bots from redirection:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=80553

You could also ignore those by identifying their User-Agent.

Comment: Same goes for all other search engines? Maybe there is a library of User_Agents i should whitelist?

Comment: There is an XML file listing them at http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml but i'm not sure how good that list is.